# Keyboard layout is switched randomly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard-layout

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** and I have experienced quite annoying keyboard layout problem.

I have still no idea, how does the default keyboard layout mechanism work.

- **Is there any "layout setting per window" functionality?**
- **Or is layout set globally?**

I am asking because it seems to me, that layout switches randomly from application to application. I am using US layout and Slovak layout and sometimes when I open new app window I am unable to write my password right for the first time because my keyboard layout is set to Slovak instead of US (without me changing it). What is even stranger is the fact, that the keyboard layout icon shows "EN" event though my layout is really "SK".

Another example is the lock screen - my keyboard layout changesa almost everytime the screen is locked (from EN to SVK). I have to change my keyboard layout back to EN almost every time I log in.

**If all this would happen once or twice, I would say, that I forgot to change layout back when typing something in Slovak. But this issue occurs really very often, and it's quite annoying.**

Does anybody experience similar issues?

Is there any way to change the keyboard layout setting policy?

Thanks a lot,
shimon

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System Settings* -> *Text Entry*. To the right you find a couple of options which you may want to change in accordance with your preferences.